# Looking for story about a group of Pegasi with the main character set to be killed, also with a seagull that winds up dead

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this story six to seven years ago. It's the first book in the series. The series has 3 or 4 books, I don't remember the exact number. The cover featured a midnight pegasus looking at something.

What I remember:

- The main character is the only midnight pegasus in 100 [?] or 200 [?] years
- Because all midnight-colored pegasi are fated to have the power to kill, the other pegasi are waiting for the day he will come "of age" to kill him
- He lives in a herd called Sun Herd [?]
- His life is threatened and he has to go to a cave place where he makes friends with a lovely seagull
- The seagull does not talk
- The seagull

> gets crushed to death by a group of horses looking for the main character

- The main character's name is either Star [?] or something like it

**Is there any book that fits this description?**

Also, I have searched for this online, but it isn't matching what I am looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is this ***[Starfire](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/20483084)*** (2014) by Jennifer Lynn Alvarez...? It's the first book in the four-part *[The Guardian Herd](https://www.goodreads.com/series/123414-the-guardian-herd)* series, the last of which was published in 2016.

This Goodreads [user review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1053218183) mentions that several things that seems to match your description, such as black pegasi being born once every 100 years, a Sun Herd, and the black pegasus being brought to a secluded cave to keep him safe from his herd, who want to kill him:

> **Star is the “black foal” – a black pegasi that is born once every 100 years.** On the black foals’ first birthday (at midnight), the Hundred Year Star gives its power to the black foal of the century. With this power, the black foal can become either the Destroyer or the Healer of the herds. Either way, the foal will become more powerful than any pegasi in Anok. **Thunderwing (and most of Sun Herd) thinks that Star will become the Destroyer, if he lives.** Star doesn’t blame them – he isn’t so sure himself! Thunderwing, the over-stallion (chief) of Sun Herd now is the head of the Guardian Herd, the herd to which the black foal is born. It is the Guardian Herd’s responsibility to keep track of the black foal and to determine it’s fate when the time came. Thunderwing gave Star until his first birthday to live and then declared that Star must be killed in case he becomes the Destroyer. **When the lead-mare of Sun Herd helps get Star to safety by bringing him to a secluded cave, she gets kicked out of Sun Herd.** She dares to go back only to warn the Sun Herd about the pegasi army about to attack the Guardian Herd because they lost track of Star. The warning didn’t help. Now Star’s friends’ lives are in danger! What can he do?

[image]